# How to represent products with varying number/type of dimensions

Tags: database, database-design

What would be a good design for a database that models the following relationships:

1. Every "Product" has a different set of relevant dimensions (width, height, density, etc.)
2. An "Item" is a product, along with values for each of that product's relevant dimensions.
3. The set of all dimensions is not known in advance.

Comment: You could use the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  Your SQL is more difficult, but your attributes can vary.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of doing this is to define a table which holds the various attributes - width, height, density, etc. Then you define a join table which would have at least three fields: the product itself, the attribute and its value. The primary key would be the product and the attribute.

This way you can easily list all the attributes for a product, list all the values for an attribute over a range of products and change the name of an attribute.

This method is to be preferred over EVA; although it's the same basic idea, it's more rigorous as the attributes are defined in a table and so act as a constraint when entering values (in other words, you can't enter a value for an attribute which hasn't yet been defined). You are also guaranteed no spelling mistakes - someone might write 'desnity' instead of 'density'.